# Result pointer in sqlite3_get_table

Tags: sqlite

sqlite3_get_table returns a pointer and that pointer must be freed after usage.

There are 3 cases:

- invalid request
- empty table
- normal return

In the 3rd case, it is clear that the table must be freed with `sqlite3_free_table()`.

In the first and second case, documentation do not say if a table is allocated (and must be freed).

Does somebody know the answer or should I use something like this:

```
ptr = NULL;
rc = sqlite3_get_table( db, &ptr, &nRow, nCol,perr);
...
if( ptr != NULL) sqlite3_free_table( ptr);
```

PS: I already know that `sqlite3_get_table()` will be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong that `sqlite3_get_table()` *will be* deprecated; it *is* deprecated.

The exact behaviour does not matter, because nobody would be so reckless as to write new code using this function.

But if you want to know the details out of curiousity:

- `sqlite3_get_table()` always returns either a valid pointer, or NULL.
- `sqlite3_free_table()` works both with a valid pointer, or NULL.